# Why does Netbeans think I'm running PHP 5.3.3?

Tags: php, netbeans

I just installed PHP 5.5 on my mac so I can run the password_hash functions included in PHP 5.5.  When I call "php -v" from the Terminal, it lets me know that I'm running PHP 5.5.18.  However, when I run my project in Safari, I call a script that just echoes 'phpversion();', which informs me that i'm running 5.3.3-7+squeeze22.  Why is this?  When I go into my project properties, it tells me that I'm configured for PHP 5.5.

My Netbeans PHP 5 Interpreter is set to "/usr/bin/php".  I have a feeling that this is the wrong interpreter, but I haven't found another one on my system.  I might just be looking in the wrong places o_O

I have no idea if this will be helpful, but a link to the website I'm testing on is http://webbox.cs.du.edu/~samkern/PHP5Test/  If you want to know anything else, please ask :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Windows? Mac? Linux?

Comment: I'm on a mac.  10.8.5 if it makes any difference.